# Changing Text In Document Created By Webform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

So I have a weird problem that is caused primarily by a lack of knowledge of how 2013 VS works, but also because of a lack of thorough documentation on the subject.

I am trying to take a document that is generated by an Employment Application form I made, and format the text on that document to something that doesn't make HR want to tear out their eye balls, but I run into a road block every time.

My favorite road block is Paragraphs.

```
Dim rng As Word.Range = Me.Paragraphs(1).Range
```

Every time I try to use this I get an error saying that paragraphs is not a member of of my webform. I am pretty sure that is because I am not importing the right references in my document. Here are the ones I am currently using:

```
Imports System.Web.Providers.Entities
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Windows.Documents
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing
```

Then I tried changing the font directly using:

```
RichTextBox1.Font = New Font(FontName.Text, 10, FontStyle.Regular)
```

but I get an error saying RichTextBox1 is not declared. When I try to change the font of:

```
LastNameBox.Font = New Font(FontName.Text, 10, FontStyle.Regular)
```

It of course tells me that Font is read only. I have been searching on google and these forums for days trying to find a solution, and I am sure it's as simple as not having the right references or imports setup. Can anyone help?

Comment: You've tagged this as ASP.NET but you're using Office Interop? Microsoft specifically recommends against that. [See this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757).

Comment: Like I said, lack of knowledge. XML will do the trick. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.